# How to allow file multiple with pundit permitted_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have an Issue model and polymorphic attachments association. Pundit is used to handle authorization and strong parameters. When I use simple file input for attachment, like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |attachments| %>
  <%= attachments.input :file, as: :file %>
```

everything goes smooth, but when I add multiple for file input, pundit reject this attribute. Here's my permitted attribute method from policy

```
def permitted_attributes
  [
      :title, :description, :project,
      assigned_users_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :email],
      attachments_attributes: [:file]
  ]
end
```

How should I change that to accept multiple file input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `:file` to `:file => []` in order to allow multiple values.

```
def permitted_attributes
  [
    :title, :description, :project,
    assigned_users_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :email],
    attachments_attributes: [:file => []]
  ]
end
```

Comment: that's exactly how I did resolve that. Forgot to mention solution here